# How to change "SKU" to a custom text in WordPress Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I want to change the SKU text in Woocommerce to a custom text. Can anyone please tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Why can't you just type in whatever you want as the SKU now? What have you tried?

Comment: You need to explain why and what you're trying to achieve because there's many ways to add additional data to a woocommerce product.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be done by many ways one of the way is by using [WooCommerce template override](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

Copy this file

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/meta.php
```

and paste it into your active theme directory some thing like this

```
/wp-content/themes/activetheme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php.
```

And replace this

```
<?php _e( 'SKU:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
```

by

```
<?php _e( 'My Text:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
```

I have tested it, and it is working.

Hop this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Or you can simply do that via this hook, copy this code to your **functions.php**
With changing text "Réf." to your Custom text.

```
 /**
 * **@snippet : Change SKU text label in woocommerce to Réf.**
 * 
 */

function translate_woocommerce($translation, $text, $domain) {
    if ($domain == 'woocommerce') {
        switch ($text) {
            case 'SKU':
                $translation = 'Réf.';
                break;
            case 'SKU:':
                $translation = 'Réf.';
                break;
        }
    }
    return $translation;
}

add_filter('gettext', 'translate_woocommerce', 10, 3);
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way to go about it